# Ljung–Box test for a multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

From Tsay's *Analysis of Financial Time Series*,

For a univariate weakly stationary time series $r_t$, 
its sample autocorrelation function $\hat{\rho}_l$ is defined as:

[image]

and the Ljung-Box test is

> [image]

For a weakly stationary multivariate time series  $r_t$, the sample lag-$l$ cross-covariance matrix $\hat{\Gamma}_l$ and sample cross-correlation matrix $\hat{\rho}_l$ of $r_t$ is defined as

[image]

[image]

The multivariate Ljung-Box test is:

[image]

[image]

I wonder how to see the test statistic for a multivariate time series is a generalization of the one for a univariate time series.

- Why do the coefficients $T(T+2)$ become $T^2$?
- Why does $\hat{\rho}_l^2$ become the trace of something?
- How is the representation in Kronecker product equivalent to (8.7)?